# Почему не используется файл bootstrap.php.cache в Symfony3 под PHP7?

Tags: php, symfony

Я заметил, что в файле [`web/app.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/web/app.php) дистрибутива `Symfony Standard Edition` есть следующая конструкция:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}
```

Т.е. в PHP7 файл `var/bootstrap.php.cache` не загружается и не используется. Почему так? В PHP7 какая-то новая фича появилась из-за которой не нужна оптимизация в виде файла со "склеенными" классами?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот файл создаётся/обновляется при запуске `composer install` и `composer update` только при помощи `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap`? Или он обновляется как-нибудь ещё? Например, при помощи какого-нибудь `cache warmer`?

Фактически, я хочу понять нужен ли этот файл в PHP7 и, если не нужен, то как я могу выпилить все упоминания о нём.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разработчики Symfony действительно [объявили](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-the-classloader-component) `ClassLoader Component` устаревшим.

Судя по тому, что говорит Nicolas Grekas в [этом топике](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20668), достаточно убрать `$kernel->loadClassCache();` и `include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';` из `web/app.php`.

Файл обновляется с помощью [SensioDistributionBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle), который заменяется на [Symfony Flex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html) в новых версиях.

Comment: Значит я правильно понял! Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, SensioDistributionBundle никак не может быть заменён на Flex. Это совсем разные вещи =)

Comment: @АндрейМиндубаев прямая цитата из readme SensioDistributionBundle: "WARNING: This bundle does not support Symfony 4. Symfony Flex is a total replacement for this bundle".